# function crypt(unknown) does not exist Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have some question on postgres I'm still new and learning new things about this database. My project wants the database to be encrypted but only for the `bytea` not including the integers and etc. when i tried using this query.

```
INSERT INTO admin (email_address) VALUES(pgp_pub_encrypt('testing',dearmor('%s'))
```

it gives me an error of message

> ( ERROR:  function dearmor(unknown) does not exist
>   LINE 2: ... (email_address) VALUES(pgp_pub_encrypt('testing',dearmor('%...)

Next sql was this.

```
INSERT INTO admin (email_address) VALUES(crypt('testing','rasenggun'));
```

Error Message: ERROR:  function crypt(unknown, unknown) does not exist

I've read some instructions that you need to install them. I have checked the php.ini as well as the httpd.conf it wasn't there. I'm sorry for being noob. I'm learning in new things.

Comment: Do you have `pgcrypto` module installed ? If no, try to google for `pgcrypto module install`. Nothing to do with php.ini or httpd.conf, it's in postgres only.

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgcrypto.html and http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createextension.html

Comment: I answered the question some time ago over at DBA: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1883/how-do-i-install-pgcrypto-for-postgresql-in-ubuntu-server/1884#1884 (replace the version with your version of pg)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is answered at: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1883/how-do-i-install-pgcrypto-for-postgresql-in-ubuntu-server/1884#1884